# r rank value in vector

Tags: r, vector, ranking, rank

I have a sequence of numbers and vectors that should be used to evaluate each of the sequence of numbers according to their ranks.

Example

```
 a <- c(20, 29, 22)
 b <- c(21, 22, 27)
 data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
 c1 <- c(12,23,34,21,33,22,35,3,5,6,7,29,49)
 c2 <- c(12,23,34,21,33,22,35,3,5,6,7,29,49)
```

How can I check the rank of each `data$a` value in vector `c1` and each `data$b` value in `c2`? Any ideas? (I abstracted the problem, but there are in sum 28 values for each individual (`a`,`b`,...) that I would need to rank according to 28 values of `c` (`c1`, `c2`, ..., `c28`)).

For the first value of `a = 20`, there would be `6` needed, since of the elements of `c1`; `12`, `3`, `5`, `6`, and `7` are all smaller.

Any ideas?

Comment: By rank do you mean position in the vector?

Comment: yes, for the first value of a, 20, there would be "6" needed, since of c1 "12", "3", "5", "6", and "7" would be smaller

Comment: @user43458 show an expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about creating a new vector with the value appended and rank that ? so creating a loop that for each element of vector`a` does:

```
rankVector=rank(append(c(a),c1))
```

And then retrieve the first value of rankVector.

The full loop would look like:

```
for (i in seq_along(a) ){

   rankVector[i]=rank(append(c(a[i]),c1))

}
```

Cheers !

Comment: ... not sure how to loop over this, but I will try!

Comment: I've added the loop for you. If you like the answer please vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the rank of your vector by using the function named rank e.g. use the following

```
   rank(a)
```

if you want to rank a vector based on another vector , you can simply use the following

```
C1[sort(order(C1)[C2])]
```

you need to clarify your question (probably add an example)

Comment: yes, for the first value of a, 20, there would be "6" needed, since of c1 "12", "3", "5", "6", and "7" would be smaller.

Comment: @nrussell you are right but he did not explain his question very well, I thought he just want to get the rank, but when i read his question several times, I found he might like to rank (position) one part of a vector based on another vector. however, i modified my question